# How to get sort content by page id?

Tags: pages, content, export, read-more

I wont to get short content in my footer area. So, I write my code as follow:

```
   $page = get_page_by_title( 'About us' );
   $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);  ?>
   <p> <?php echo $content; ?> </p>
```

By this code I get full page content. So how can I get short content till my setted `<--read more-->` link in the about us page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your best solution will be to setup postdata and the making use of the `the_content()` template tag

```
$post = get_page_by_title( 'About us' );
setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <p> <?php the_content(); ?> </p>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy :-)